# Which is the best way to use image as object property in Flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, datamodel

I used a Model of object in My app Flutter/ Dart. But how to render image when I want to set property of that class object on front end.
Example Album class

```
class Album{
String title;
Image mg;
String description;
Album({this. Title, this. Mg, this. Description});
}
```

When I want to access image like obj1.img as under:

```
new Raw Image(obj1.img)
```

It gives ERROR.

Comment: Please include the error/stack trace you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the images are retrieved using an URL. It is not a good design to store it as an image object because this has implications like:

- image objects are referenced in Album objects so they consume a considerable memory during the lifecycle of the object(most probably, the list of Albums is retrieved at app start and it is kept till the user closes the app).
- usually, the asset url is stored in database, so when getting the entities and parsing them, you need another pass to download the image for each entity.

Here it is a concept:

```
class Album {
  final String title;
  final String coverUrl;
  final String description;
  Album({this.title, this.coverUrl, this.description});
}

Container(
  child: Image.network(artist.coverUrl,),
);
```

If you need caching, check [CachedNetworkImage](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image).